# How to step through a program using Netbeans?

Tags: java, debugging, netbeans, step-into

For part of my testing, I need to be able to step through the program, and take screenshots as different functions are executing. However, I can't seem to get the program to run through the functions I want them to.

I've tried stepping into the program, it goes through the main method just fine and then it breaks. As there is input required to move onto the next form, the program won't step through any further and some of the functions I need to step over are on different forms etc.

How can I do this so it will step every action I do? Like when I login and click the login button it will step through the code of the button and steps through any other method calls as well.

This is vital for my work and I can't seem to get Netbeans to do it.

Any help?

Edit: I can right click and debug a single form, but I can't step it if I do that.

Comment: I don't use Netbeans, but generally you need to set a `breakpoint` where you want your code to stop and allow you to step through. Set a breakpoint where you want to debug.

Comment: Look at this video tutorial [Using the NetBeans Debugger](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=joWldbcp1So).